# Pandas - How to use a column as the string value in command

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

I am trying to create a fiscal quarter column in pandas. If the fiscal year-end is March, I could do this with the following code:

```
df['fiscalquarter'] = df['Date'].dt.to_period('Q-MAR')
```

However, instead of 'MAR', I want to use the column in my dataframe that has the month abbreviation. My column values are JAN, FEB, MAR, etc. How do I tell pandas to look at the value in that column (fiscalmonth) to create the quarter?

Output of print(df.head()):

```
           ID  fiscalmonth        Date  DateSubYear fiscalmonthabr  
5021        1            2  2001-03-29         2001            FEB  
5780        2            2  2001-04-03         2001            FEB  
7024        3            2  2001-05-02         2001            FEB  
7307        4            2  2001-05-11         2001            FEB  
8076        4            2  2001-06-14         2001            FEB
```

I would like to see:

```
           ID fiscalquater 
5021        1       2002Q1   
5780        2       2002Q1   
7024        3       2002Q1   
7307        4       2002Q1  
8076        4       2002Q2
```

Comment: Can you update your post with the output of `print(df.head())` please?

Comment: you need to make a date out of it?

Comment: I edited my comment with the output and my desired column. @Corralien

Comment: I want the year and the quarter @mathtick. I have updated it with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
fiscal_quarter = lambda x: x['Date'].to_period(x['fiscalmonthabr'])
df['fiscalquater'] = df.assign(fiscalmonthabr='Q-' + df['fiscalmonthabr'],
                               Date=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])) \
                       .apply(fiscal_quarter, axis=1)
print(df)

# Output
      ID  fiscalmonth       Date  DateSubYear fiscalmonthabr fiscalquater
5021   1            2 2001-03-29         2001            FEB       2002Q1
5780   2            2 2001-04-03         2001            FEB       2002Q1
7024   3            2 2001-05-02         2001            FEB       2002Q1
7307   4            2 2001-05-11         2001            FEB       2002Q1
8076   4            2 2001-06-14         2001            FEB       2002Q2
```

Comment: I got an error message: "AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'to_period'". @Corralien

Comment: What is the output of `print(df.dtypes)`?

Comment: Date is an object. Using ```df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])``` to change it to a datetime. Should that fix the error?

Comment: Yes. That's what I did on my side

Comment: Do you know how I can get the year from this?

Comment: Use `df['fiscalquater'].dt.year`

Comment: I get an error ```AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values``` The type is object.

Comment: `fiscalquater` is a PeriodIndex. Do you convert the column as `string`?

Comment: No, I didn't convert anything. If it matters, the end month changes, so the fiscal period varies depending on the ending month. I tried to take the first four numbers from the variable, but it said that it couldn't be split.

Comment: Try: `df['fiscalquater'].astype(str).str[:4].astype(int)` as workaround.